# How to prevent splitting by comma on expressions guarded by double quotes?

Tags: python, string, csv, split

I have a line (from a csv) that looks like this:

```
line = 'M1,After.Life,Agnieszka Wojtowicz-Vosloo,Agnieszka Wojtowicz-Vosloo,"Drama, Thriller",2009/10/2/,80'
```

When I do `print line.split(',')` I get:

```
['M1', 'After.Life', 'Agnieszka Wojtowicz-Vosloo', 'Agnieszka Wojtowicz-Vosloo', '"Drama', ' Thriller"', '2009/10/2/', '80']
```

which is undesirable because it also splits "Drama, Thriller". In other words, what I want as the result is:

```
['M1', 'After.Life', 'Agnieszka Wojtowicz-Vosloo', 'Agnieszka Wojtowicz-Vosloo', '"Drama Thriller"', '2009/10/2/', '80']
```

Any ideas to a simple approach? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead. You have a CSV format, and that module knows how to handle quoted values properly.

```
import csv

with open(somefilename, 'rb') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    for row in reader:
        # row is a list of string values found on each line, ready split, 
        # with qouted values preserved.
```

Quick demo for your example line:

```
>>> import csv
>>> inputfile=['M1,After.Life,Agnieszka Wojtowicz-Vosloo,Agnieszka Wojtowicz-Vosloo,"Drama, Thriller",2009/10/2/,80\n']
>>> list(csv.reader(inputfile))
[['M1', 'After.Life', 'Agnieszka Wojtowicz-Vosloo', 'Agnieszka Wojtowicz-Vosloo', 'Drama, Thriller', '2009/10/2/', '80']]
```

Note that the quotes have been removed but the comma is still there as part of the value.

Comment: thank you, just what I needed! I will accept the answer when I can ;)